# How to increase key size in Memcached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached

#### Problem

I'm getting the error:

```
key too long "rack:session:BAh7...."
/usr/local/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/memcache-client-1.8.5/lib/memcache.rb:703:in `get_server_for_key'
/usr/local/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/memcache-client-1.8.5/lib/memcache.rb:920:in `request_setup'
/usr/local/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/memcache-client-1.8.5/lib/memcache.rb:885:in `with_server'
```

When I looked at memcache-client-1.8.5/lib/memcache.rb:703

```
def get_server_for_key(key, options = {})
  raise ArgumentError, "illegal character in key #{key.inspect}" if key =~ /\s/
  raise ArgumentError, "key too long #{key.inspect}" if key.length > 250
  ...
end
```

Also according http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ#What_is_the_maxiumum_key_length?_(250_bytes) the max length is 250 bytes.

Since this is production and is pretty hard to replicate this error, i figured i can ask here if any one had the same issue before.

#### Question 1: *Can I remove the statement from the memcache-client?*

#### Question 2: *Is there any way to reduced the key size in rails? I'm using the below in my production.rb*

```
config.action_controller.session_store = :mem_cache_store
```

Answer (score 4):

If your keys are too long, hash each key before storing it in Rails.cache

Something like this:

```
def hash_key(string)
  Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(string)
end
```

Comment: You should take care of collisions.

Comment: Indeed. Like @rbajales says, you cannot just hash the keys as that can introduce collisions and you'll end up overwriting other keys and retrieving incorrect values.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost certainly seeing this because you're switching from the cookie store to memcached. Your browser still has the old session cookie, with the long ID. You need to delete this cookie from your browser and the problem will go away.

If you're switching from cookie store to memcached on a production site, this will be a problem because you don't have control over your user's browsers. You'll probably need to change the session key to avoid problems in this case.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> key too long "rack:session:BAh7...."
> ```

Are you dumping your entire session into the cache as a key? If you are manually adding to the cache, please post that code.

Comment: Not manually adding to the cached. I configured rails to use memchaced, in my production.rb

    config.action_controller.session_store = :mem_cache_store

Answer (score 0):

That limit seems to be imposed by memcached itself, not Ruby, so removing that statement will not help you. The memcached documentation suggests that if your key size is longer than 250 bytes, you're probably doing something wrong anyways.

Comment: simply changed the session_store to use :mem_cached_store instead of cookie.

config.action_controller.session_store = :mem_cache_store